# SQL writing custom query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store

I need to write a SQL Query which generates the name of the most popular story for each user (according to total reading counts). Here is some sample data:

```
story_name | user  | age | reading_counts
-----------|-------|-----|---------------
story 1    | user1 | 4   | 12
story 2    | user2 | 6   | 14
story 4    | user1 | 4   | 15
```

This is what I have so far but I don't think it's correct:

```
Select *
From mytable
where (story_name,reading_counts)
IN (Select id, Max(reading_counts)
      FROM mytable
      Group BY user
)
```

Comment: Hint: Order by should do

Comment: Just use order by.. Keep it simple..

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have? Any specific error messages? Unexpected behavior? Can you describe the exact behavior you observed and what you expected?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output.  Do not use images; provide formatted text. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: This is not being inputted into a database to find the answer. So I cant really check it. My main concern is that I dont know if the question is asking me to generate just the name with the largest reading count per user or all the story names per user and order it by largest reading count

Comment: I will also vote to reopen, but only after the question has been edited with an MCVE. Right now, it doesn't have one and remains off-topic for that reason. Describe exactly the results you got, what results you expected, and what the difference is. If you understand what it is you are trying to accomplish, this shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @RobertColumbia please look at the question again after the edit

Comment: You can't use id in your subquery when ID doesn't actually exist in your dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), you can first determine the maximum `reading_counts` for every user (`Group By` with [`Max()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max))
- Now, simply join this result-set to the main table on `user` and `reading_counts`, to get the row corresponding to maximum `reading_counts` for a user.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT 
  t1.* 
FROM mytable AS t1 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT t2.user, 
         MAX(t2.reading_counts) AS max_count 
  FROM mytable AS t2
  GROUP BY t2.user 
) AS dt 
  ON dt.user = t1.user AND 
     dt.max_count = t1.reading_counts
```

Comment: should the last line be 
     dt.Max_count = t1.reading_counts 
because the max count gets defined in the derived table (dt)

Comment: @KlaidiZiaj it was a typo. Thanks for spotting it. fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE user IN
(SELECT user, max(reading_counts)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user)
```

Comment: Code only answers are not good. Please add some explanation to the answer.

Comment: This is just wrong. But seems fitting as an answer to someone who is clearly fishing for an answer to a homework.